# Matlab: Compare array to other arrays

Tags: arrays, matlab, if-statement, median

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Matlab, comparing array using if statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12683393/matlab-comparing-array-using-if-statement)

Hey guys i have an array much like the following

```
A = [2 4 6 8 ; 3 5 7 9 ; 1 4 6 9]

row_median = [ 5 6 5 ]
col_median = [ 2 4 6 9 ]
```

from this data i want to create another array, called `MedianMap`. I need to use an IF statement (I know there are easier ways like `meshgrid`, however I want to know how to do it this way) to compare all the values in array `A` with their corresponding row and column medians under the following conditions:

- if the value is greater than both the row and column median a "1" is assigned to the median map
- if the value is less than both the row and column median a "-1" is assigned to the median map
- otherwise a 0

Comment: Also: [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?

Answer (score 2):

You appear to be a fairly new user, so welcome to SO. Two things: 1) If you think I or someone else has answered your question, then please click the tick mark next to the answer. As for number two, well...

2) This sounds like a homework question (ie the fact that you want to use IF statements even though you know there are better ways). If this is the case, then please note for future reference that people are more likely to provide help if you demonstrate in the question that you've at least attempted to solve the problem yourself.

On the chance that this isn't a homework question, here are two solutions (one with IF statements, the other without):

```
%#Setup
A = [2 4 6 8 ; 3 5 7 9 ; 1 4 6 9];
Med1 = median(A, 1); %median of each column
Med2 = median(A, 2); %median of each row
T = size(A, 1);
N = size(A, 2);

%#Your IF solution
MedianMap2 = NaN(T, N);
for t = 1:1:size(A, 1)
    for n = 1:1:size(A, 2)
        if A(t, n) > Med1(1, n) && A(t, n) > Med2(t, 1)
            MedianMap2(t, n) = 1;
        elseif A(t, n) < Med1(1, n) && A(t, n) < Med2(t, 1)
            MedianMap2(t, n) = -1;
        else
            MedianMap2(t, n) = 0;
        end
    end
end

%#A better solution
I1 = (A > ones(T, 1) * Med1) .* (A > Med2 * ones(1, N));
I2 = (A < ones(T, 1) * Med1) .* (A < Med2 * ones(1, N));
MedianMap1 = zeros(T, N) + I1 - I2;

%#Print output
MedianMap1
```

Comment: First off you have been a great help. Secondly how do you print the median map?

Comment: for t = 1:1:size(A,1)                                                         for n = 1:1:size(A,2)                                 fprintf('MedianMap %d\n', MedianMap);                                                        end end

Comment: is that along the lines? as it is showing errors

Comment: `dlmwrite('YourFileNameHere', MedianMap1);`

Answer (score 2):

This is also a job for [bsxfun](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html):

```
 result = zeros(size(A));
 result( bsxfun(@gt,A,row_median') & bsxfun(@gt,A,col_median) ) =  1;
 result( bsxfun(@lt,A,row_median') & bsxfun(@lt,A,col_median) ) = -1;
```

Comment: The OP had asked this question before, and I gave precisely this answer :) Anyway, now he wants to do the same thing but *with* an `if`-statement for some reason, so strictly speaking...this is not an answer to the question.

Comment: yeah, looked through your comment after posting this and noticed just that, left it up to point out that bsxfun is built just for this.

Comment: Upvoting you regardless. This is the way to go, the `if` statement is just some silly homework constraint.